# Pycharm Edu debugger doesn't work

Tags: python

I'm using Pycharm Edu and every time I try to start the debugger I get this error:

Error running 'FILE_NAME': com/jetbrains/edu/learning/statistics/EduUsagesCollector

I tried to use the debugger both Linux and OSX but I get the same error on both platforms. Any idea how I can solve this?